# How do I test an image src and alt value using capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm trying to write  test the value of alt text + src of an image using capybara and the css selectors.

any idea s to test both in single xpath ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking existence of images and favicons with RSpec and Capybara](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583316/checking-existence-of-images-and-favicons-with-rspec-and-capybara)

Answer (score 35):

A slightly simpler way will be to use an id for that image:

`page.find('#profile-avatar')['src'].should have_content 'default.png'`

Updated for rspec 3:

`expect(page.find('#profile-avatar')['src']).to have_content 'default.png'`
`expect(page.find('#profile-avatar')['alt']).to match(/some-value/)`

Comment: imo this is the best way to go b/c it uses css instead of ugly xpaths

Comment: the alt portion of the OP's question is the same, with 'alt' for 'src'.

Comment: modernized, I did: expect(page.find('#profile-avatar')['alt']).to have_content 'your_alt_text'

Answer (score 8):

You can check multiple attributes using xpath

```
assert page.has_xpath("//img[@src = 'some_value' and @alt='some_value']")
```

Comment: This needs to say "//img" instead of "//image" in order to work for me, but with that change made it helped me. Thanks!

Comment: The correct form is

`assert page.has_xpath?("//img[@alt='some_value' and @src = 'some_value']")`

Answer (score 7):

```
variable=find(:xpath, "//img[@class='class_name']")
variable['src'].should == "url"
variable['alt'].should == "text"
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `Should` is a bit out dated. `Expect` is RSpec's new expectation syntax.
2. Separating expectations in their own specs is good practice.
3. Personal preference: I avoid `have_content` as much as possible since it is not exactly verifying the value of the attribute that I want and just performs a `HaveText(*args)`. It can cause false positives.

```
before(:all) do
  @avatar_image = find('#profile-avatar')
end

it 'has correct src' do
  expect(@avatar_image[:src]).to eq("some_url")
end

it 'has correct alt text' do
  expect(@avatar_image[:alt]).to eq("some_text")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having some trouble because the src of my image had some dynamic values, so I did this:

```
find(locator+' img')['src'].include?(img_src).should be_true
```

I don't really care about the path, just if the file name was the correct

Answer (score 1):

It does not answer directly your question but if some people fancy debugging ease over speed, I'd suggest using this syntax :

```
find(:xpath, "//img[@class='avatar']/@src").text.should match /some url/
find(:xpath, "//img[@class='avatar']/@alt").text.should match /some text/
```

as the error will be more explicit if it fails. (it will actually display the value of `src` and `alt`).

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, this works perfectly:

```
find("img[src='https://some-url.com/image.jpg']")
```

or with embedded ruby

```
find("img[src='#{@post.image}']")
```

Here is an example I recently used:

```
test "Showing a company" do
  visit companies_path
  click_link @company.name
  
  assert_title @company.name
  assert_selector :link, href: @company.url
  assert_selector "h3",  text: @company.title
  assert_selector "p",   text: @company.description

  find("img[src='#{@company.image}']")
end
```