# How to test existance of favicon with Rspec Test?

Tags: rspec

I've uset expect(page).should have_xpath("favicon").But it doesn't work. I use Ruby ob rails Rspec Capybara Cucumber

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking existence of images and favicons with RSpec and Capybara](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583316/checking-existence-of-images-and-favicons-with-rspec-and-capybara)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this thread that already answers the question [Checking existence of images and favicons with RSpec and Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583316/checking-existence-of-images-and-favicons-with-rspec-and-capybara) let me know if it helps you.